# Checking if entry exists

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I'm trying to create a login app. I want it to do nothing more than either store the account info on a db if the username is not already used. Problem is, no matter what I try, I cannot check if the username is already in the db

I've tried to get both LiveData from my query, as well as String?, as shown below with no success

I have also tried setting an onConflict strategy other than ignore, and then putting my addUser function call in a try-catch block, but it crashes

```
@Entity(tableName = "Users_table")
data class User(
    @PrimaryKey var username: String,
    @ColumnInfo var firstName: String,
    @ColumnInfo var lastName: String,
    @ColumnInfo var email: String,
    @ColumnInfo var password: String
)
```

---

```
@Dao
interface UsersDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    fun addUser(user: User)

    @Query("Select username from users_table Where username = :username")
    fun getUser(username: String): String?

}
```

---

```
@Database(entities = [User::class], version = 1)
abstract class UsersDatabase: RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun userDao(): UsersDao


    companion object{
        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE: UsersDatabase? = null

        fun getDatabase(context: Context): UsersDatabase {
            val tempInstance = INSTANCE
            if (tempInstance != null) {
                return tempInstance
            }
            synchronized(this) {
                val instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context.applicationContext,
                    UsersDatabase::class.java,
                    "users_database"
                ).build()
                INSTANCE = instance
                return instance
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
class UsersRepository(private val usersDao: UsersDao) {


    suspend fun addUser(user: User){
        usersDao.addUser(user)
    }

    suspend fun getUser(username: String) {
        usersDao.getUser(username)
    }

}
```

---

```
class UsersViewModel(application: Application): AndroidViewModel(application) {

    //private val getUser: LiveData<List<User>>
    private val repository: UsersRepository

    init {
        val userDao = UsersDatabase.getDatabase(application).userDao()
        repository = UsersRepository(userDao)
        //getUser = repository.getUser
    }

    fun addUser(user: User) {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            repository.addUser(user)
        }
    }

    fun getUser(username: String) {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            repository.getUser(username)
        }
    }

}
```

---

```
...


        if (mUsersViewModel.getUser(binding.etRegUsername.text.toString()).toString() != "0") {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Username already exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        } else {
            mUsersViewModel.addUser(user)
            Toast.makeText(this, "User successfully created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }



 ...
```

Comment: Not sure if room table names are case sensitive, but i see you named your table "Users_table" and in the Query you used "users_table".

Answer (score 1):

You can use this query to get count of users with given user name

```
@Query("Select count(*) from users_table Where username LIKE :username")
fun getUser(username: String): Int?
```

and use this to check if there are user

```
if (mUsersViewModel.getUser(binding.etRegUsername.text.toString()) != 0) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Username already exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    } else {
        mUsersViewModel.addUser(user)
        Toast.makeText(this, "User successfully created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
```

Comment: I've tried that as well, exactly as written, but the app crashes

Comment: what does crash say?. Can you share it here?

Comment: 2022-07-07 11:12:32.962 6816-6816/com.example.singlescreenregistration E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.singlescreenregistration, PID: 6816
    java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "kotlin.Unit"

Comment: if (mUsersViewModel.getUser(binding.etRegUsername.text.toString()).toString() != "0")

solves the crash, but is always != 0, no matter what random username I use

Comment: Although not being able to convert it to an Int, means the query is not returning a number, as expected

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. Fetch all the data first and then compare it with your editText's data(username,email)
2. Set an query inside the `UsersDao` , to check whether an entry with same values exists or not.